# How to fetch data displayed in a TableView cell and display it in a textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView in a view controller where I display data from an API call, now if the user selects a tableview cell(say row 2 in the TableView), I want to fetch that data(Data in row 2 of TableView) and display it in the Textfield on the same screen. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one, When user select's particular UITableViewCell then that cell contents will be show in UITextField.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell= tableView1.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

        if let txtVal = cell?.textLabel?.text {
            textField.text = txtVal
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is you can show show the `UIAlertController` with `textField` on `didSelect` of tableViewCell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Edit Data", message: "Edit corresponding detail", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter name"
        textField.text = yourArray[indexPath.row]            
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        //Edit data on array
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have data from from webservice which you are displaying on your UITableview say `arrWebServiceData`. and you have index of row where user clicked on say `index`. Simplest way is to get Data from `arrWebServiceData` at `index` and use it to display on test field.

for example:

NSArray *arrWebServiceData; //you are storing data from Wevserice here.

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
    let index = indexPath.row;
    let dataAtIselectedIndex = yourArray[indexPath.row]  ;
    //If data is string, dirctly display it on text field,or if its dictionary, set object of diction on your text field.

}
```